# get rid of the arrow in previous_post_link?

Tags: next-post-link

How can I hide or disable this `«` sign in front of  `previous_post_link`?
I can't find it anywhere - it only shows up on the generated page.

This is the code I am using:

```
    <?php
        $nextPost = get_next_post();
        $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID);
        next_post_link('%link',''.$nextthumbnail.'');
        $next_value = get_post_meta( $nextPost->ID, 'subtext', $single = true);

?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your `next_post_link`:

```
 <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . $prevthumbnail . '' ); ?>
```

Per the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link), the first parameter specifies what will we be shown (thanks Chip!)

Comment: Hi - I don't get your answer...sorry. I have the issue of course for both directions...

Comment: The `&laquo;` is coming from the default first parameter to `previous_post_link()`. That default value is "`$format='&laquo; %link'`". [See source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1309). To change it, you need to pass a different value for the first parameter.

Comment: thank you! Thank you! Just worked! I changed the link-template.php.

Comment: Mark this answer as accepted then. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can define whatever you want. You can wrap `%link` (the actual link to the post) the way you like it most:

```
<?php next_post_link( '<strong>%link</strong>' ); ?>
```